# How to set weight for geo-elem-pair-query in MarkLogic structure query?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I'm trying to rewrite the following cts query using XML structure query:

```
cts:element-pair-geospatial-query(
  fn:QName("http://www.example.com/2009/foo","wgs84"), 
  fn:QName("http://www.example.com/2009/foo","latitude"), 
  fn:QName("http://www.example.com/2009/foo","longitude"), 
  cts:circle("@12 53.411541,-2.9900994"),
  ("coordinate-system=wgs84","score-function=reciprocal","slope-factor=4"), 
  32
)
```

I converted it into:

```
<geo-elem-pair-query>
                     <parent ns="http://www.example.com/2009/foo" name="wgs84" />
                     <lat ns="http://www.example.com/2009/foo" name="latitude" />
                     <lon ns="http://www.example.com/2009/foo" name="longitude" />
                     <fragment-scope>documents</fragment-scope>
                     <geo-option>coordinate-system=wgs84</geo-option>
                     <geo-option>score-function=reciprocal</geo-option>
                     <geo-option>slope-factor=4</geo-option>
                     <circle>
                        <radius>12.0</radius>
                        <point>
                           <latitude>53.411541</latitude>
                           <longitude>-2.9900994</longitude>
                        </point>
                     </circle>
</geo-elem-pair-query>
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to add `weight` into `<geo-elem-pair-query>`. Accordingly to [MarkLogic documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/7.0/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_18303) it seems to be unsupported (but cts equivalent supports it). I've tried to add `<weight>32.0</weight>` but it doesn't work.
Do you know if there is a way to add weight to geo-elem-pair-query structure query?

Comment: You've discovered a bug -- geo-elem-pair-query doesn't support weight but should. Could you use the XML serialization of the cts:element-pair-geospatial-query() as yielded by `<a>{cts:element-pair-geospatial-query(...)}</a>/*`?

Comment: @ehennum Can you elaborate on your idea? How can I use `cts:element-pair-geospatial-query` in Java API.

Comment: The `QueryManager.newRawCtsQueryDefinition​()` factory takes the JSON or XML serialization of a cts:query() and returns a `RawCtsQueryDefinition` that can be passed to the `QueryManager.search()` or `DocumentManagersearch()` methods. See http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/QueryManager.html#newRawCtsQueryDefinition-com.marklogic.client.io.marker.CtsQueryWriteHandle- and, for the general technique on passing raw queries to search(), http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_45762

Comment: As an alternative, the additional-query element in the QueryOptions can contain the serialiization of a cts:query (which is AND-related to the rest of the query) as described here http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_67369